# Let $C$ be a $[n,k]_q$ code. Then: $d = n - k + 1$ iff the generator matrix $G$ contains respectively $k$ linear independent columns (MDS code)

Tags: linear-algebra, information-theory, coding-theory

> Let $C$ be a $[n,k]_q$  code. Then: $d = n - k + 1$ iff the generator matrix  $G$ contains $k$ linear independent columns, meaning that choosing $k$ arbitrary columns of $G$ always leads to $k$ linear independent vectors.

I thought a while about this, but I can't come up with anything specific. $d$ is the minimum distance that two vectors of $C$ can possess, respectively the minimal amount of components $v_i$ of a vector $v \in C$ that are different from $0$. I think since there are $k$ columns that are linear independent from each other, then the code words can differ at least at $k$ components from each other.

It migt be wise to use:

$C$ possesses the minimal distance $d$ iff there are always $d-1$ columns of the check matrix $H$ that are linear independent, but $d$ columns that are linear dependent.

Applying this to our given problem, the theorem could be rewritten as:

$C$ possesses the minimal distance $n - k + 1$ iff there are always $n - k$ columns of the check matrix $H$ that are linear independent, but $n - k + 1$ columns that are linear dependent.

Note that $H = ((-G')^T|E_{n-k})$.

Comment: The word "respectively" looks out of place. Are you sure you got this right?

Comment: Thanks! Deleted it. What I meant: If you choose $k$ columns of $G$, then those $k$ columns are linear independent from each other. But you could also choose $k$ other columns of $G$ and they would be linear independent too. But if you choose $k+1$ columns instead, they would be linear dependent. I don't know what's the right word in English though.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Take $n=6, k=3, q=2$, with $G=[I_{3\times 3 } | 0_{3 \times 3}]$. Then $G$ has $k$ LI columns, but the minimum distance is $1$

Comment: Yeah, thought about such an example too and don't understand it either, to be honest. It just doesn't seem to make sense. I saw a lot of proofs on the internet for it though, but the arguments didn't fit to the stuff we did in the lecture.

Comment: Okay, I guess your example doesn't work for the following reason: Every vector is linear dependent to the 0-vector. So if you choose 3 arbitrary columns, you wouldn't be able to guarantee that they are indeed linear independent. Maybe I should rewrite the problem like this.

Answer (score 1):

First, notice that $d$ cannot exceed $n-k+1$ ([singleton bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_bound#Linear_codes)), hence $d = n-k+1$ is equivalent to $d \ge n-k+1$

If any $k$ subset of columns of $G$ is LI, then $d \ge n-k+1$.  Suppose this were false; then $d\le n-k$, i.e., there exists a (non zero) codeword $c_0$ with at least $k$ zeros. But this cannot be. Because $c_0 = uG$ and any $k\times k$ submatrix of $G$ is full rank (that is, not only the columns are LI, but also the rows).

The converse is similar. Suppose $d \ge n-k+1$. Then there cannon exist a $k$ subset of columns of $G$ that is LD. Because then the respective $k\times k$ submatrix would be singular, hence also its rows would be LD, and then there would exist some $c =uG$ that produces at least $k$ zeros in the codeword.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But why does $d \le n-k$ imply that there exists a codeword with at least $k$ zeros?

Comment: You know that $d$ equals the minimum weight of the (nonzero) codewords?

Comment: Yes, I do know that.

Comment: Well, then $d \le n-k$ implies there is codeword with weight equal or less than $n-k$ (i.e. $k$ or more zeros)

Comment: Okay, I understood that one. Furthermore, why isn't is possible that any codeword $c_0$ has at least $k$ components that equal $0$? I don't comprehend why it follows from the fact that any $k \times k$ submatrix of $G$ has full rank.

Comment: If the submatrix has full rank, no linear combination of its rows (excepting $u=0$) can produce a zero sub-vector (hence $k$ zeroes in $c$)

Comment: Yes, but why is that the case? Is there a theorem for it? And what do you mean by a zero sub-vector, if I may ask?

Comment: I see that a $k \times k$ submatrix with full rank cannot produce a zero-vector, but it's still possible that it produces a vector that contains some zeros, right? Plus, we didn't even consider the rest of $G$, which could also produce some zeros. So I don't see how this tells me that there can't be any vector with at least $k$ components that equal $0$.

Comment: That is true for any $k$ components of $c$. Any $k$ components of $c$ cannot be zero. Think about it.

Comment: Okay, I will try it! Thanks!

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer the whole question though. I am supposed to show / assume that $d = n - k + 1$. You assumed / showed that $d \ge n - k + 1$.

Comment: It's the same thing. Clarification added.